# How to run a MySQL procedure from a Linux shell script and store its output in a file

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I have a mysql procedure which I want to run from a shell script in linux and store the output in a log file. But my script is not working. Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
source CX20-PIM-properties.prop    
status=$(mysql -u $user -h $host -D $database -se "call fetchFromPAsIsToPIDX()")    
if [ $status ]; then  
     echo "Procedure executed successfully" |  tee  procedure_output.log  
else  
 echo "Procedure execution failed" |  tee procedure_output.log  
fi
```

And the output is below:

```
[anurag@pimdev0 ~]$ ./load-from-AsIs-to-IDX.sh   
 Procedure execution failed
```

Comment: what does status include? can you `echo $status`

Comment: also did you test if your command work ? `mysql -u $user -h $host -D $database -se "call fetchFromPAsIsToPIDX()" > output.txt`

Comment: @Simonare $status is not returning any value,. It shows empty when I echo $status. I tested the command for other sql queries like select and it works but in case of procedure, my script is unable to run the procedure query or show its output

Answer (score 0):

You should store the return value of cmd in status not stdout of cmd.

```
#!/bin/bash    
source CX20-PIM-properties.prop    
if [ `mysql -u $user -h $host -D $database -se "call fetchFromPAsIsToPIDX()" &> /dev/null` ]; then  
     echo "Procedure executed successfully" |  tee  procedure_output.log  
else  
 echo "Procedure execution failed" |  tee procedure_output.log  
fi
```

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion. Let me check if this approach works or not